# ICriteria and Linq to NHibernate together

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, icriteria

How can I create one query using both ICriteria and Linq?
Example:

```
var q = Session
.Query<T>()
.Where(x.Id == 1)
.ToCriteria()
.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Title", "Ayende @ Rahien"))
.List<T>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should use QueryOver for it:

```
var q = Session
.QueryOver<T>()
.Where(x.Id == 1)
.Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property<T>(x.Title), "Ayende @ Rahien"))
.List<T>();
```

Comment: Thanks for such quick answer!

Comment: The accepted answer is misleading. Criteria and LINQ can't be mixed. What happens is that QueryOver is a strongly-typed wrapper for Criteria; the `Where` statement there is NOT LINQ.